# I'm trying to make a vertex group on one side of a model, but the selection keeps mirroring on the other side too. How do I stop this?

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups

[image]

The model I'm working on. I'm trying to prevent the selection from mirroring on the other side as well. I plan on having at least independent 5 vertex groups so that I can control the fall of the hair that I'm going to add in. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you were using the Mirror Modifier have you applied it?

Comment: Yep. I used it to make the model all the way from the beginning. Do I have to delete it?

Comment: you need to apply it, not delete it

Answer (score 2):

The Mirror Modifier is a non-destructive action within Blender. Meaning the changes are virtual and the results do not make any permanent changes.

[image]
(This is just a UV sphere with half the vertices deleted and then a Mirror Modifier added.)

[image]

When you edit one side of the Mesh a representation of the same change is shown in the mirrored vertices.

If you want the vertices to exist independantly of the Modifier then you must click Apply.

[image]

Now the Modifier is applied any changes apply to only the selected vertices.

[image]

The same is true of Vertex groups. As the geometry only exists in one place (i.e. the left) when the Modifier is working. As soon as you apply it you can affect any of the now real vertices.