# Why does only selecting one face select multiple faces occasionally?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, selection-tools

I'm very new to 3D modeling in general. I've been working on a Blender project over the past day, and recently, when I would edit one face on the right side of my model, it would select/edit another face on the left side. Also, I can't select anything on the left side at all. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

[image: I only selected the face on the right of the camera...]

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122101/im-trying-to-make-a-vertex-group-on-one-side-of-a-model-but-the-selection-keep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made a [linked Duplicat](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/duplication.html#linked-duplicates) by pressing `Alt + D` insted of `Shift+ D`.

You can unlink them like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/how-to-unlink-a-linked-duplicate).

[[image: 2]].